# Probability of exactly $K$ events out of possible $N$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So I've stumbled upon this question in Grimmett and Stirzaker's text. I have their solutions manual, which starts off like this:
[image]

The line above, where the statement is expanded into sums, is where I'm stuck. Would be glad if someone could elucidate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write 
$$\bigcap_{i\in S}A_i \cap\bigcap_{j\in S^c}A_j^c =A_I \cap \left(\bigcup_{j\in S^c}A_j \right)^c,$$
hence 
$$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i\in S}A_i \cap\bigcap_{j\in S^c}A_j^c\right)
=\mathbb P(A_I)-\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{j\in J^c}(A_I\cap A_j)\right).$$
Then the formula follows from the inclusion-exclusion formula.